# Store not dispatch success action

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, angular-ngrx-data

I had such a problem that, store not dispatch success action, in all other cases, everything works for me, but in this it does not

My actions

```
export const getPrintingEditions = createAction(
PrintingEditionActions.GET_PRINTING_EDITIONS,
props<{paginationQuery?: PaginationQuery, filter?: PrintingEditionFilter}>()
)

export const getPrintingEditionsSuccess = createAction(
PrintingEditionActions.GET_PRINTING_EDITIONS_SUCCESS,
props<PagedResponce>(),
)

export const getPrintingEditionsFailure = createAction(
PrintingEditionActions.GET_PRINTING_EDITIONS_FAILURE,
props<{error: any}>()
)
```

My effect

```
getPrintingEditions$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(printingEditionActions.getPrintingEditions),
mergeMap(action => this.printingEdition.getPrintingEditions(
  action.paginationQuery,
  action.filter
).pipe(
  map(pagedResponce => printingEditionActions.getPrintingEditionsSuccess(pagedResponce)),
  catchError(err => of(printingEditionActions.getPrintingEditionsFailure(err)))
)
```

)))

Reducer code

```
on(printingEditionActions.getPrintingEditionsSuccess, (state, action) =>
peAdapter.setAll(action.data, {
  ...state,
  pageNumber: action.pageNumber,
  pageSize: action.pageSize,
  nextPage: action.nextPage,
  previousPage: action.previousPage,
})
```

),

I'm use entity state for manage entities

When you don't do anything on the page, you wait, it starts to glitch.

I think, problem not in actions, effect and reducer, but I'm don't understand where problem and how solve it

link to repository on github. This code locale in store
https://github.com/mrshk-vv/book-store-client

Comment: :) You have to replace `mergeMap` with `switchMap` in effect.

Comment: I tried, didn't help

Comment: what is `printingEditionActions`? `import * as printingEditionActions from '...'` ?

Comment: yes, of course)

Comment: i see, but you use same in action with const `PrintingEditionActions.GET_PRINTING_EDITIONS_SUCCESS`. It imported from another. Isnt it?

Comment: that enum, in action class

Comment: But your action function not contain in enum. :) and you use `printingEditionActions.getPrintingEditionsSuccess` reference.

Comment: use import this `import { getPrintingEditions, getPrintingEditionsSuccess } from '.../action.ts'` and use function ref like  `ofType(getPrintingEditions)` and `map(pagedResponce => getPrintingEditionsSuccess(pagedResponce)),`

Comment: look at my github repository

Comment: your advice didn't help